# Besides the main thread is there any other special thread?

Tags: objective-c

For example, if we use ABAddressBook, we must use only one thread.

Well, I don't want that one thread to be the main thread.

However, all other threads are not unique. How do I create NSOperationQueue for example, that only uses one special thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAy be this will help you out.
yes you can perform operations on background thread too other than the mail thread .

`PerformSelectorInBackground:withObject:` is a possible solution.

```
dispatch_queue_t workQ = dispatch_queue_create("bgWorkQ", 0);
dispatch_async(workQ, ^{
    // This code is now running in a background thread.
    // Do all your loading here...

    });
});
dispatch_release(workQ)
```

here is a link for NSOperation Queue Sample Tutorial
[enter link description here](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/16/cocoa-tutorial-nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use address book types originating from an `ABAddressBook` on the same queue that you created the `ABAddressBook` instance. It does not have to be the main queue. If you want to pass references between queues, you have to import them into another `ABAddressBook` instance, created on the destination queue. This is a relatively inexpensive operation.

Comment: You mean it doesn't have to be the same thread? Only that it's in the same queue?

Comment: Queues reuse threads as the system sees fit, however a dispatched job will run on one thread. `ABAddressBook` is not thread safe, so you should create `ABAddressBook` instances for each thread you work with.

Comment: What? How did you deduce that from my answer?