# Can ABAddressBook be Used by Multiple Thread on the same serial Queue?

Tags: objective-c, abaddressbook

This is the documentation in iOS 6

> Users are able to grant or deny access to contact data on a per-app
>   basis. To request // access to contact data, call
>   ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion. This will not // block the
>   app while the user is being asked to grant or deny access. Until
>   access has // been granted, a non-NULL ABAddressBookRef will not
>   contain any contacts and any attempt to // modify contacts will fail
>   with CFErrorRef returning kABOperationNotPermittedByUserError. // The
>   user will only be prompted the first time access is requested; any
>   subsequent calls // to ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions will use the
>   existing permissions. The completion // handler is called on an
>   arbitrary queue. If the ABAddressBookRef is used throughout the app,
>   // **then all usage should be dispatched to the same queue** to use
>   ABAddressBookRef in a // thread-safe manner

It doesn't say same thread anymore. Just same queue. So it's okay to use NSOperationQueue to access this ABAddressBookRef? Can I?

Note:
That question ask whether we can tell NSOperationQueue to use one specific thread. This one ask if ABAddressBook can be used ACROSS threads within the same NSOperationgQueue (perhaps a serial one)

There are 2 DIFFERENT way to accomplish the same thing. Hence the question is different.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Besides the main thread is there any other special thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176659/besides-the-main-thread-is-there-any-other-special-thread)

Comment: Why are you posting multiple questions about the same topic?  I would recommend spending more time on the Apple Developer site.

Comment: That question ask whether we can tell NSOperationQueue to use one specific thread. This one ask if ABAddressBook can be used ACROSS threads within the same NSOperationgQueue (perhaps a serial one)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use across different jobs of an operation queue, because jobs may be dispatched on different threads.